# Subsetting rows based on names in a PCA

Tags: r

I want to subset my data by site names on a PCA.

I have matrix data of roughly 200 rows. They list site names, years, and environmental data. I had to transform my data. I then ran a PCA on ALL of my data (total of 20 sites). For the scope of the project, I want to only display SOME sites on the biplot, but using the arrow lengths of the entire dataset. Because I have a mix of - and + numbers the subset command is not working. I am using two different plotting commands: cleanplot and autoplot.

Creating a var.subset doesn't work with the -/+. 
I have also tried the fviz_pca_ind command with select.ind, and that has not worked either.

I am relatively new to R and am not well versed in all packages etc, and have been googling this problem for a few hours now.

```
## a small/abridged sample of the type of data I am working with. 

view(env)

site     coral_cover      soft_coral    algae
A   -1.299642738    -0.899981100    0.31297676
A   -0.543243466    -0.899981100    -0.37866568
A   -1.369679707    -0.899981100    -0.37866568
B   -1.243613162    -0.899981100    -0.24033719
B   -1.411701889    -0.899981100    -0.37866568
B   0.269185382 0.232783249 -0.37866568
B   0.759444169 -0.220322491    -0.30950144
C   1.473821260 -0.107046056    -0.37866568
C   -0.669310011    0.346059684 -0.30950144
C   0.241170594 1.592100468 -0.37866568
C   1.781983926 -0.673428230    -0.37866568
D   2.324770441 -0.050407838    1.35044042
D   0.507311079 -0.220322491    0.10548403
D   -1.327657526    0.346059684 -0.37866568
D   -0.669310011    0.912441858 -0.37866568
E   0.871503321 -0.333598926    -0.37866568
E   0.643883169 -0.475194469    -0.20575507
E   0.003044897 -0.899981100    0.17464827
```

```
# PCA on the environmental data
env.pca <- rda(env) 


##Plot
dev.new(width = 8,
        height = 6,
        title = "PCA biplots - env - autoplot", 
        noRStudioGD = TRUE
)
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
autoplot(prcomp(env), 
         data= env.all, 
         colour= "reserve_status",  
         shape= "site",
         loadings= TRUE, 
         loadings.colour = 'black',
         loadings.label=TRUE, 
         loadings.label.colour = 'black',
         mar.percent = 0.5
) 

##This command will show all 5 sites, but what if I only wanted to display "A", "C" and "E"
```

[This is the plot with everything on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKGGc.png)

This is basically what I want, but to be able to choose which sites I want. I got this plot as a result of a code error. 
[What I want-ish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BbkA.png)

Comment: can you add a screen shot of the final plot ?

Comment: look for the filtering section at this link: http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/112-pca-principal-component-analysis-essentials/#filtering-results

Comment: Thanks! I will check out the filter section, and I added the plots.

Comment: I will try the select.ind command again. I had tried that previously, but maybe was structuring my sentence wrong- thanks for the helpful link!